# Meaning of the momentum vectors $\mathbf{k}$ in electronic band structure

Tags: condensed-matter, momentum, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

In solid-state physics, I struggle to understand momentum vectors $\mathbf{k}$ in reciprocal space. We usually draw a picture of a Brillouin zone as follows (hexagonal in this case):

[image]

And we can then calculate a band structure of a given material and get a band structure plot (a graphene, for instance):

[image]

My confusion arises in the meaning of the $\mathbf{k}$ itself. In the Brillouin zone, it can hint that different $\mathbf{k}$ corresponds to different *physical position* of the electron in space. But I know, that it is not true. How does an electron in the $\Gamma$ point (with the $\mathbf{0}$ momentum) really differ from the one in the $K$ point?

Is the difference in the momentum alone and therefore in band structure we only "scan" different momenta and calculate energies of electrons with that given momentum?

I think I understand the overall picture but I just have a problem of the idea not *clicking* to the right spot and detachting from the *real space* picture.

Comment: What do you mean with "in the Brillouin zone, it can hint that different  corresponds to different physical position of the electron in space"? k has nothing to do with physical positions of the electron in space, however the measured energies have something to do with magnitude of the potentials at physical positions in space.

Comment: @secr I know it does not signify a position in a real space but what I always find misleading is the saying like "The direct gap in located in the Gamma point"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In solid-state physics, I struggle to understand momentum vectors $\mathbf{k}$ in reciprocal space.

> My confusion arises in the meaning of the $\mathbf{k}$ itself. In the Brillouin zone, it can hint that different $\mathbf{k}$ corresponds to different *physical position* of the electron in space.

No, the $\mathbf{k}$ value has nothing (or very little) to do with the position of "the electron" in space. The $\mathbf{k}$ value certainly tells you something about how the *wave function* varies in space between lattice sites, but that is rather different from "the physical position of the electron in space."

Remember, too, that $\mathbf{k}$ only makes sense in the context of the Bloch theory of a solid (i.e., the non-interacting single-particle theory of a solid). (Of course, this is an absurd theory *a priori* since a solid has many many interacting electrons. It is only justified *a posteriori*.)

Anyways, what the $\mathbf{k}$ tells you about is how the phase of this mythical single-particle wavefunction varies from unit cell to unit cell in the solid:
$$
\psi_{\mathbf{k}}(\vec r) = e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r})\;,
$$
where $u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r})$ is a periodic function, with the same periodicity as the real-space lattice.

For example, if the wavefunction at $\mathbf{r} = 0$ is
$$
u_{\mathbf{k}}(0)
$$
then the wavefunction at $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{R}$, where $\mathbf{R}$ is some other lattice site, is
$$
e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R}}u_{\mathbf{k}}(0)\;.
$$

Comment: This might be the source of my confusion. I still try to connect the wavevector in Bloch theory too much to the real world and the real "momentum" of the particle. I tend to think about the particles in different points in k-space as them having different velocities.

Comment: Yeah, this is why people sometimes use the term "crystal momentum" instead of "momentum."

Comment: And, remember, the *momentum* of the electron does not have to be conserved since the hamiltonian is not translationally invariant (for arbitrary translations). The hamiltonian has an external potential (due to the atoms of the lattice) that is only invariant under translations by the lattice vectors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_momentum

Answer (score 1):

You do an experiment where you measure $E$, the eigenvalues of the energy operator and $\vec k$, the eigenvalues of the Fourier-transformed momentum operator. Since the eigenvalues don't change under Fourier transformation, $\vec k$ are the eigenvalues of the original momentum operator. You don't measure the eigenvalues of the position operator. Between $\Gamma$ and K, you variate the momentum-eigenvalues. $\vec{k}$ is not the eigenvalue of the position operator. Due to periodicity of the potential $V(x)$, you get specific $\vec{k}(E)$-modes. In these modes, you get a resonance between state $|k\rangle$ and the potential $V$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle can be easily understood in the distribution of momenta of molecules of a gas inside a container. It has nothing to do with location. There are some important differences however:

1. It is not possible to have more than 2 (opposite spins) electrons with the same $\mathbf k$
2. Crystals are not spherically symmetrical, so the density of $\mathbf k$'s is not the same for the several directions in space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an intuitive picture, think of $\mathbf{k}$ as a vector which defines the "waviness" of the electron's wavefunction spread out in the crystal just like a wave propagating in the surface of water. Since the crystal has translational symmetry, these waves look almost periodic, with the exception of a smooth change in the phase from cell to cell given by $\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}$ where $\mathbf{r}$ is a lattice vector.

The higher the $\mathbf{k}$, the smaller the wavelength, which means the wave is more wiggly. Oppositely, a small $\mathbf{k}$ produces a wavefunction where there's little variation in the phase of the wave from cell to cell; meaning, the electron wavefunction looks more periodic.

Comment: So if we have a band structure where we have a very small gap in the K point but a bigger gap in the Gamma point, then we could say that its easier to excite electrons of bigger wavelengths, as the K point corresponds to higher k vector?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you can say that. It is easier for electrons to hop from the first band to the second band if they are at the K point rather than if they are in the Gamma point in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The $k$ vector is a quantum number. With the band index, k vector, and spin orientation, you have uniquely identified an electron wave function (in the independent electron approximation).

It also tells the the group velocity of that wavefunction, which is needed in integrals of electrical and thermal conductivity.